# Rails 3.1 : Upload file on AWS S3 with PaperClip / Mongoid / SimpleForm <-- Nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, mongoid, paperclip, nested-forms

I have a problem in my web application. All my uploads on AWS S3 work, but in the form below, the file is saved correctly in the database but not on S3.

**The form code (views/users/show.html.haml) :**

```
= simple_nested_form_for @user, :url => save_reply_classaction_opponent_user_path(@classaction, @user.opponent, @user), :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
    = f.simple_fields_for :reply, @reply do |builder|
      = hidden_field_tag :filter_name, @filter_name
      = hidden_field_tag :filter_type, @filter_type

      %dt= builder.label "Statut", required: false
      %dd= builder.input :state, as: :select, label: false, collection: ["Remboursement effectué", "Demande de remboursement acceptée / En cours", "Remboursement partiel", "Demande rejetée"], include_blank: false
      %dt= builder.label "Montant du remboursement", required: false
      %dd= builder.input :redemption_amount, :placeholder => "Montant en euros", as: :string, label: false
      %dt= builder.label "Date du remboursement", required: false
      %dd= builder.input :redemption_date, as: :date, start_year: Time.now.year, end_year: Time.now.year-5, discard_day: false, order: [:day, :month, :year], label: false
      %dt= builder.label "Justificatif", required: false
      %dd= builder.input :redemption_proof, as: :file, label: false
        - unless @reply.redemption_proof_file_name.nil?
          %dd= link_to(@reply.redemption_proof_file_name, @reply.redemption_proof.url, :target => "_blank")
      %dt= builder.label "Commentaires", required: false
      %dd= builder.input :note, as: :text, label: false

    .clearfix
    = f.submit "Valider la réponse", :class => "le-button button-2"
```

**The Model "Reply" code (models/reply.rb) :**

```
# encoding: utf-8
class Reply
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Paperclip
  include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes

  field :state, type: String
  field :redemption_amount
  field :redemption_date, type: Date
  field :note, type: String

  has_mongoid_attached_file :redemption_proof,
    :storage => :s3,
    :path => "/redemption_proofs/:hash.:extension",
    :hash_secret => "jojgHojKbjspvuufRsey78jkHj278",
    :s3_credentials => File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 's3.yml')

  embedded_in :user, inverse_of: :reply

end
```

**The Model "User" code (models/user.rb) :**

```
# encoding: utf-8

class User

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :first_name
  field :last_name
  field :email
  field :token
  field :disabled_at, type: DateTime

  embedded_in   :opponent, :inverse_of => :users
  embeds_one    :reply

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :reply

end
```

**The User controller (controllers/users_controller.rb) :**

```
def show
  if @user.reply.nil?
    @reply = @user.build_reply
  else
    @reply = @user.reply
  end
end

def save_reply
  @filter_name = params[:filter_name]
  @filter_type = params[:filter_type]
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    redirect_to classaction_opponent_user_path(@classaction, @opponent, @user, :moderation => '1', :filter_name => @filter_name, :filter_type => @filter_type)
  end
end
```

**Below that's i have in my console after form validation :**

> Started PUT
>   "/action-de-groupe/commandes-non-livrees/opponents/52d3e7622c1bb94852000009/users/52dd20d52c1bb96e6800000d/save_reply"
>   for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-28 15:01:01 +0100
>
> Processing by UsersController#save_reply as HTML
>
> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"QHTxNr27NMBsbND66Rfwde/cPMV06d9T6WEIjIPPagc=",
>   "filter_name"=>"", "filter_type"=>"with_profile",
>   "user"=>{"reply_attributes"=>{"state"=>"Remboursement effectué",
>   "redemption_amount"=>"768", "redemption_date(3i)"=>"24",
>   "redemption_date(2i)"=>"2", "redemption_date(1i)"=>"2014",
>   "redemption_proof"=>#>,
>   "note"=>"test commentaire", "id"=>"530b6c4b2c1bb9cc5e000008"}},
>   "commit"=>"Valider la réponse",
>   "classaction_id"=>"commandes-non-livrees",
>   "opponent_id"=>"52d3e7622c1bb94852000009",
>   "id"=>"52dd20d52c1bb96e6800000d"}
>
> MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 UPDATE
>   database=class_actions_development collection=classactions
>   selector={"_id"=>"52d3e7622c1bb94852000008"}
>   update={"$set"=>{"opponents.0.users.12.updated_at"=>2014-02-28
>   14:01:01 UTC,
>   "opponents.0.users.12.reply.redemption_proof_file_name"=>"barbeuk.jpg",
>   "opponents.0.users.12.reply.redemption_proof_content_type"=>"image/jpeg",
>   "opponents.0.users.12.reply.redemption_proof_file_size"=>117083,
>   "opponents.0.users.12.reply.redemption_proof_updated_at"=>2014-02-28
>   14:01:01 UTC, "opponents.0.users.12.reply.note"=>"test commentaire"}}
>   flags=[] (0.1080ms)

**Below that's i have in the database for the document "user" :**

> "reply" : {   "_id" : ObjectId("530b6c4b2c1bb9cc5e000008"),   "note" :
>   "test commentaire",   "redemption_amount" : "768",    "redemption_date" :
>   ISODate("2014-02-24T00:00:00Z"),  "redemption_date(1i)" : "2014",
>     "redemption_date(2i)" : "2", "redemption_date(3i)" : "24",
>     "redemption_proof_content_type" : "image/jpeg",
>     "redemption_proof_file_name" : "barbeuk.jpg",
>     "redemption_proof_file_size" : 117083,  "redemption_proof_updated_at"
>   : ISODate("2014-02-28T14:01:01.646Z"),    "state" : "Remboursement
>   effectué" }

**Too, the logs on Heroku while the upload :**

> 2014-02-27T13:31:43.810211+00:00 app[web.1]: [AWS S3 404 0.11337 0
>   retries]
>   head_object(:bucket_name=>"classactions_production",:key=>"redemption_proofs/530cdb6074581998b500002a/original.jpg")
>   AWS::S3::Errors::NoSuchKey No Such Key

Thanks for your help ! I hope this case will help someone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this could be the problem:

```
s3_credentials: File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 's3.yml')
```

I would highly recommend setting the `s3` credentials in your `ENV` variables, preferably using the [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) gem:

```
#cmd
rails generate figaro:install

#config/application.yml
S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "your_key"
S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "your_key"

#app/models/image.rb
has_mongoid_attached_file :redemption_proof,
    storage: :s3,
    path: "/redemption_proofs/:hash.:extension",
    has_secret: "jojgHojKbjspvuufRsey78jkHj278",
    s3_credentials: {
       access_key_id: ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
       secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }

#cmd
rake figaro:herkoku
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a good gem and i note it !
But all my uploads on S3 in my web application work with my current configuration so i think the problem is not here.